# How can one express $\mathbb{Q} / \mathbb{Z}$ as a direct sum of $\mathbb{Q}$ and $\mathbb{Z} / p$ for $p$ prime?

Tags: modules, homological-algebra, injective-module

Consider the $\mathbb{Z}$ modules $\mathbb{Q}$ and $\mathbb{Z} / p$ for $p$ prime. I have a result that says that every injective $\mathbb{Z}$ module is a direct sum of these modules. I also know that $\mathbb{Q} / \mathbb{Z}$ is an injective $\mathbb{Z}$ module, being divisible. How can I reconcile these two notions and express $\mathbb{Q} / \mathbb{Z}$ as a direct sum of $\mathbb{Q}$ and $\mathbb{Z} / p$ for $p$ prime? This doesn't seem possible to me. Am I interpreting one of my stated results in the wrong way?

Comment: $\newcommand{\Z}{\mathbb{Z}}$It's not $\Z/p$, but rather the [Prüfer group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pr%C3%BCfer_group) $\Z(p^{\infty})$.

Comment: @AndreasCaranti Isn't that an answer? Why are you putting it in a comment?

Comment: @Arthur, right, will move it to an answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$\newcommand{\Z}{\mathbb{Z}}$It's not $\Z / p$, but rather the [Prüfer group $\Z(p^{\infty})$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pr%C3%BCfer_group).

Answer (score 2):

Expanding on what Andreas has said.

$\mathbb{Z}/p$ is not injective (tensor it in $0\to\mathbb{Z}\to\mathbb{Z}\to\mathbb{Z}/p\to 0$).  What you should have gotten instead is $\mathbb{Z}(p^\infty)=\injlim_{n\to\infty}\mathbb{Z}/p^n$ being divisible (i.e. injective).  Then
$$
\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}=\bigoplus_{p\text{ prime}} \mathbb{Z}(p^\infty)
$$