# Independence of some events with respect to Haar measure

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, independence, topological-groups, haar-measure

In order to fulfill details in a proof, I came across with the following fact which, whenever true, allows me to conclude the line of reasoning.

Here is the stage:
I have an abelian group $G=\Bbb{Q}^n/\Bbb{Z}^n$ (here $n$ is a positive integer) and it is equipped with the discrete $\sigma$-algebra.
Furthermore, let us denote by $\Gamma_n$ the dual of $G$, i.e. the group of all group homomorphisms form $G$ to the complex unit circle $T=\{z\in\Bbb{C}\colon \lvert z\rvert=1\}$ and denote by $\mu$ the probability Haar measure on $\Gamma_n$.

What I want to prove is the following:
the events $A=\{\psi\in\Gamma_n\mid \psi(a+\Bbb{Z}^n)=0\}$ and $B=\{\psi\in\Gamma_n\mid \psi(b+\Bbb{Z}^n)=0\}$ are $\mu$-independent whenever $a,b\in\Bbb{Q}^n\setminus \Bbb{Z}^n$ are linearly independent over $\Bbb{Z}$, i.e.
$$\mu(A)\cdot \mu(B)=\mu(A\cap B).$$

Although I spent on this much time, I got the least in the sense that I'm stuck.
In some sense,  that I'm not able to make more precise, I expect all the sets $A$, $B$ and $A\cap B$ have $0$ measure wrt $\mu$.

Any suggestion or contribution is appreciated.

**Edit**
As @AlexRavsky remarked below, the correct (and more general) notion of independence to be used here is the following: $a,b$ are lineraly independent iff $ma+kb=0$ implies $m=k=0$, not the one I used in my original question.

Comment: Doesn't $\mu(A)$ follow from translation invariance? Isn't $B$ a translate of $A$?

Comment: @mathworker21 A translation of $A$ would have the form $A+\varphi=\{\psi+\varphi\in\Gamma_n\mid \psi(a+\Bbb{Z}^n)=0 \}$, which doesn't seem to be the case, right?

Comment: i guess. what do elements of $\Gamma_n$ look like?

Comment: @mathworker21 $\Gamma_n$ is the set of all homomorphisms from the group $G=\Bbb{Q}^n/\Bbb{Z}^n$ to the unit complex circle $T$ (see above)

Comment: lol, thats not what i asked. whatever, ill come back to this later maybe

Comment: @mathworker I apologize, either I don't understand your question or I can't answer it.

Comment: it was a kinda vague question. i was just wondering if there's a nice characterization of the elements of $\Gamma_n$. Like, the dual of $\mathbb{Z}_n$ is all stuff $x \mapsto e^{2\pi i \frac{mx}{n}}$. I'll come back later though. nice question :)

Comment: What topology is imposed on $G$ and whether elements of $\Gamma_n$ are required to be continuous maps?

Comment: @AlexRavsky Literally, referring to $\Gamma_n$, it is stated what follows: "think of this as space of all homomorphisms from $\Bbb{Q}^n/\Bbb{Z}^n$ to $T=\Bbb{R}/\Bbb{Z}$ with the pointwise topology and the group operation of pointwise addition. Since $\Bbb{Q}^n/\Bbb{Z}^n$ is discrete, countable and torsion we have that $\Gamma_n$ is compact, metrizable and zero-dimensional" and a reference is given to Hewitt, Ross "Abstract Harmonic Analysis 1" for a general discussion of Pontryagin duality.

Comment: @AlexRavsky So, (1) $G=\Bbb{Q}^n/\Bbb{Z}^n$ is equipped with the discrete topology (but I don't know why it is considered; maybe it coincides with the quotient topology); (2) Pontryagin duality is required, so I think continuity is required (at least, this is what I found in Hewitt, Ross), but it is not explicitly mentioned and I don't know if the argument works without contunuity.

Comment: OK. Then the $\sigma$-algebra generated by open sets of $G$ consists of all subsets of $G$ and every map on $G$ is continuous.The discrete topology on $G$ doesn’t coincide with the quotient topology $\Bbb Q^n/\Bbb Z^n$.

Comment: I guess $n$ in “$na+mb\ne 0$" is not necessarily the same $n$ as in $\Bbb Q^n/\Bbb Z^n$.

Comment: @mathworker21 I answered your [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3634732/independence-of-some-events-with-respect-to-haar-measure/3651669#comment7489740_3634732) [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3634732/independence-of-some-events-with-respect-to-haar-measure/3651932#3651932).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the group $G=\Bbb Q^n/\Bbb Z^n$ is torsion, it has no pairs $a,b$ of independent elements. Even for any element $a\in G$ there exists $k$ such that $ka=0$. So we formulate the following condition on linear independence of elements $a$ and $b$ instead: for all integers $m,k$ such that $ma=kb$ we have $ma=kb=0$.

Let $a,b$ be any elements of $G$, $\langle a\rangle$, $\langle b\rangle$, and $\langle a,b\rangle$ be subgroups of $G$ generated by $a$, $b$, and $\{a,b\}$ respectively. Then sets $A$, $B$, and $A\cap B$ be the annihilators of groups $\langle a\rangle$, $\langle b\rangle$, and $\langle a,b\rangle$, respectively.

Let $H$ be a finite subgroup of $G$. Its annihilator $H^\perp$ is a closed subgroup of $\Gamma_n$ and so $\mu(H^\perp)^{-1}$ equals to the index $|\Gamma_n: H^\perp|$.  According to the duality theory (see, for instance Theorem 37 in [Pon]), $H$ is the group of characters of the group $\Gamma_n/H^\perp$. So $\Gamma_n/H^\perp$ is isomorphic to the group of characters of the group $H$ (see, for instance, Theorem 37 in [Pon]). But, since $H$ is a finite group, the group of its characters is isomorphic to $H$, see [Pon, §36.G]. That is, $|\Gamma_n: H^\perp|=|\Gamma_n/H^\perp|=|H|$.

Thus $\mu(A)=|\langle a\rangle|^{-1}$, $\mu(B)=| \langle a,b\rangle |^{-1}$, $\mu(A\cap B)=| \langle a,b\rangle |^{-1}$.
Thus $\mu(A)\mu(B)= \mu(A\cap B)$ iff $|\langle a\rangle|\cdot |\langle a\rangle|=|\langle a,b\rangle|$. A homomorphism $h:\langle a\rangle\times \langle b\rangle\to \langle a,b\rangle$, $(x,y)\mapsto xy$  for any $x\in \langle a\rangle$  and $y\in \langle b\rangle$, is surjective. So $|\langle a\rangle|\cdot |\langle b\rangle|=|\langle a,b\rangle|$ iff $h$ is injective, which holds iff the kernel of $h$ is zero, that is iff for all integers $m,k$ such that $ma=kb$ we have $ma=kb=0$.

*References*

[Pon] Lev Pontrjagin, *Continuous groups*, 2nd ed., M., (1954) (in Russian).

Comment: Probably this should be the argument of another question (and, in this case, I'll open another). (1) In the above notation, I've tried to show $\mu(\psi\in\Gamma_n\mid \forall q+\Bbb Z\in\Bbb Q^n/\Bbb Z,\,\psi \in\langle q+\Bbb Z\rangle^\perp\Leftrightarrow q/p+\Bbb Z\in\langle q+\Bbb Z\rangle^\perp)=1$. To do this, I've fixed $q+\Bbb Z$. Using $\psi\in\langle q/p+\Bbb Z\rangle^\perp\rightarrow\psi\in\langle q+\Bbb Z\rangle^\perp$ and that the order of $q/p+\Bbb Z$ is $p$ times the order of $q+\Bbb Z$, I got that the measure for fixed $q$ equals $1-(p-1)/p |\langle q+\Bbb Z\rangle|^{-1}$.

Comment: and since the order of $q+\Bbb Z$ can be arbitrary large, I think I proved what I was looking for.

Comment: (2) Suppose $e_1$, $e_2$ denote two elements of the standard basis for $\Bbb Q^n$. Intuitively, it seems reasonable, but do you see a formal way to show that the sets $E_p=\{\psi\in\Gamma_n\mid \psi\in\langle e_1/p\rangle^\perp, \psi\notin\langle e_2/p\rangle^\perp\}$, where $p$ varies among the primes, are $\mu$-independent, in the sense that the probability of a finite intersection of them equals the products of their single probabilities?

Comment: Finally, thanks for the answer and for the precise reference you gave me.

Comment: PS: in the above comments, $\Bbb Z$ should be read $\Bbb Z^n$

Answer (score 2):

Here we answer a [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3634732/independence-of-some-events-with-respect-to-haar-measure/3651669#comment7489740_3634732) by mathworker21

> what do elements of $\Gamma_n$ look like?

It is well-known that the group $\Bbb Q/\Bbb Z$ is a direct sum of Prüfer groups $\Bbb Z(p^\infty)$, see, for instance, [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3236826/how-can-one-express-mathbbq-mathbbz-as-a-direct-sum-of-mathbbq-an) thread. Thus $G$ is $n$-th power of this sum. By [DPS, Proposition 3.1.2], its group of characters $\Gamma_n$ is a Cartesian product of the group of characters of  Prüfer groups. By Example 61, [Pon], the group of characters of the group $\Bbb Z(p^\infty)$ is the group $\Bbb Z_p$ of $p$-adic integers, so $\Gamma_n$ is topologically isomorphic to $\prod_{{\Large p}\mbox{ is prime} } \Bbb Z_p^n$.

*References*

[DPS] Dikran N. Dikranjan, Ivan R. Prodanov, Luchezar N. Stoyanov. *Topological Groups*, Marcel Dekker, New-York, 1990.

[Pon] Lev Pontrjagin, *Continuous groups*, 2nd ed., M., (1954) (in Russian).

Comment: just got to this. thanks!